# Using Javascript to check for required but unselected radio options on dynamic forms - unsure why the following doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

My application allows individuals to create custom forms, with a variety of fields. They can also specific if a field is required, and this is checked client-side prior to submission.

The following works well for text fields:

```
for(var i=0; i < form.elements.length; i++){

   if(form.elements[i].value === '' && form.elements[i].hasAttribute('required') {
       // code to run if not selected...
   }
   ...
```

Equally, if you can do something like the following for checkboxes:

```
      if(form.elements[i].type=="checkbox") {

          if(form.elements[i].checked!==true && form.elements[i].hasAttribute('required')) {
          // whatever...
          }
          ....
```

But when I try and apply a similar logic to radio buttons, it doesn't work:

```
      if(form.elements[i].type=="radio") {

          if(form.elements[i].checked!==true && form.elements[i].hasAttribute('required')) {
          // whatever...
          }
          ...
```

I've had a look around and can't understand why the above logic fails?

Comment: Have you already tried `form.checkValidity()`?

Comment: I can't tell from the code posted, but is is possible that ALL of the radio buttons are sharing the same name attribute and at least 1 of them is checked elsewhere on the form?

Comment: Hi, no names are automatically generated randomly, so no shared names.

Comment: Please show the form and radio html.